# Datetime.valueof auto convert to UTC (GTM+0) when store in DB salesforce

Tags: apex, datetime

Today I face with problem about date time in apex.

Value of date time from response api is:

```
2022-07-29T02:21:34.000Z
```

But after I use Datetime.valueOf like below

```
Datetime newDateTime = Datetime.valueof(
    string.valueof('2022-07-29T02:21:34.000Z')
        .replace('T', ' ')
);
```

Then insert this newDateTime to DB and I see the value date time is

```
2022-07-28T17:21:34.000Z
```

Maybe after I use Datetime.valueof then salesforce store date time value of UTC (GMT+0)
So how can I store value from API response will be

```
2022-07-29T02:21:34.000Z
```

Not

```
2022-07-28T17:21:34.000Z
```

Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: I found solution from this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944880/how-to-create-a-datetime-in-apex-given-a-datetime-string

Comment: I found solution from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944880/how-to-create-a-datetime-in-apex-given-a-datetime-string